# Search function works on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a search function to my website.  Right now it's very rudimentary, and the search is simply pulling results from MySQL using select.  The problem is, the search works great when I test it on localhost but doesn't work at all when I put it on the server.  When it is used it simply selects the entire database.  I believe the problem is that the variable isn't getting passed to the search results page, but I don't know.

Here's the code for the search box.  It is in a referenced file called "header.php":

```
<html>
<head>

<body>
<div class="title"><img style="width:100%;" src="title.gif" /></div>
<div class="search">Search: 
<form style="display:inline" name="search" action="search.php" method="get"><?php echo"         <input type='text' name='query' />";?>
<a href="javascript: searchSubmit()"><img src="seo.png" alt="Search" title="Search" />   </a></form></div>
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="index.php#home">home</a></li>
<li><a href="submit.php?title=&desc=">post an idea</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">about us</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">contact us</a></li>
<li><a href="login.php">log in</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the code from search.php:

```
<?php
$search=$_GET['query'];
$search=mysql_real_escape_string($search);
?>
<html>
<head>
<?php
echo "<title>Search: $search</title>";
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="title"><img style="width:100%;" src="title.gif" /></div>
<div class="search">Search: 
<form style="display:inline" name="search" action="search.php" method="get"><?php echo"    <input type='text' name='query' value='$search'/>";?>
<a href="javascript: searchSubmit()"><img src="seo.png" alt="Search" title="Search" /></a></form></div>
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="index.php#home">home</a></li>
<li><a href="submit.php?title=&desc=">post an idea</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">about us</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">contact us</a></li>
<li><a href="login.php">log in</a></li>
</ul>
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("date_ideas") or die(mysql_error());

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ideas WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%' ORDER BY    post_date DESC");
echo "SELECT * FROM ideas WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%' ORDER BY post_date DESC";

echo "<span id='none'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$id=$row['id'];
echo "<h2 class='center'><a href='ideaview.php?id=$id' title='View ".$row['title']."     Description'>" . $row['title'] . "</a><br/>";
echo "<span class='date'>";
$date=$row['post_date'];
$time=time();

if (($time-$date)<120)
{
echo "Posted 1 minute ago";
}

else if (($time-$date)>120&&($time-$date)<3600)
{
$minutes=($time-$date)/60;
echo ("Posted " . round($minutes) . " minutes ago");
}
else if (($time-$date)>3600&&($time-$date)<7200)
{
echo "Posted 1 hour ago";
}
else if (($time-$date)<86400&&($time-$date)>7200)
{
$hours=($time-$date)/3600;
echo ("Posted " . round($hours) . " hours ago");
}
else if (($time-$date)<172800&&($time-$date)>86400)
{
echo "Posted 1 day ago";
}
else
{
echo ("Posted on " . date("m-d-y",$date));
}
echo "</span></h2>";
}
echo "</span>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("none");
if (none.innerHTML == "")
{
none.innerHTML="<p class='center'>There are no ideas matching your search</p>";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lastly, here's the code for the javascript used to submit the form:

```
var valid=true;

function validate(field, helptext, type, min, max, field1)
{
var x=field.value;
var text=document.getElementById(helptext);
if (x==null || x=="")
{
if (text!=null)
    {
    text.innerHTML="Please input "+field.id;
    }
valid=false;
}
else if (type=="length")
{
valLength(min,max,field,helptext);
}
else if (type=="email")
{
valEmail(field,helptext);
}
else if (type=="pass")
{
valPass(field, field1, helptext);
}
else
{
if (text!=null)
    {
    text.innerHTML="";
    }
valid=true;
}
}

function searchSubmit()
{
validate(search.query);
if (valid==true)
{
search.submit();
}
else
{
alert("Please enter a search term");
}
}
```

As I said, when I use it on my localhost on my computer, it works perfectly, returning only the rows where title matches the search.  When I put it on the server, however, it returns all the rows in the table.

Comment: Please provide complete and formatted code

Comment: You don't give the body of `searchSubmit()`, which is kind of important.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'm new at this, I thought less code would be easier to read.  I'll post complete code.

Comment: @Frzibee: No, you're right, narrowing down the testcase is good. Posting all your production code is bad. However, since `searchSubmit()` is invoked in your testcase and therefore may be pertinent, also including a narrowed-down version of that would be helpful. (Note, though, that I believe I have solved the issue, and it has nothing to do with that function.. so no need to bother now. :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything in the code given that would cause this. I think your analysis is correct; I'd imagine `$_GET['query']` is empty for some reason.

You could make your code a little more robust by doing an explicit check for this: you want that to be an error case, not "return everything" case. But besides confirming your theory, this won't solve the problem outright.

The only thing I can think of is to make sure that `$_GET` exists on your server; it was [introduced](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) in PHP 4.1.0, which is now a very long time ago. Still, it's possible that the PHP on your remote server is ancient.

Good luck!

---

**Update**

You're using `mysql_real_escape_string`, which [requires a connection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), before you make the connection. If there isn't one, one is attempted using default parameters which is working on your local machine, but not on your [presumably more secure] production server.

This is causing the escaping to fail, and `FALSE` to be written into `$query`.

Just use `mysql_escape_string` which doesn't require a connection.

Comment: That can't be the problem, as I use the $_GET on another page and it works fine.

Comment: Also, I did add an error check into the page, and the problem is definitely that the variable is empty.  The $_GET isn't working.

Comment: The update makes sense, thank you.  It also fits with what I found, which is that if I put the connection before the $_GET it works great.

Comment: @Frizbee: Great! BTW, `$_GET` isn't a function or an "action"; it's the name of an array variable. Just so you know.

Answer (score 1):

try to printout the query to see if it injects $search value correctly (if search is not null)

```
echo "SELECT * FROM ideas WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%' ORDER BY post_date DESC";
```

Comment: On localhost:'SELECT * FROM ideas WHERE title LIKE '%apple%' ORDER BY post_date DESC.'  On server:'SELECT * FROM ideas WHERE title LIKE '%%' ORDER BY post_date DESC.'  For some reason it's not passing the variable correctly.

Comment: Try a print_r($_GET) to see the transmitted data

Comment: Interesting - it still returns Array ( [query] => idea ) just like my localhost.  Why wouldn't that be passed into the variable I'm trying to use?

Comment: maybe problem is in mysql_real_escape_string.
Try to 
$search=sprintf('%s',$_GET['query']); 
 and comment out // $search=mysql_real_escape_string($search);